# prevent program from terminating when hitting enter

Tags: c

I'm very new to C right now and I was given a template to code on as per my homework.
I need to allow users to hit enter key without typing anything and keep the program from terminating.

```
if(!fgets(cmdline, MAXLINE, stdin)){                    
    break;
}
```

this is what I'm using to take user input. I also have a parser that checks for '&' and '\n' at the end of input for future arguments. But when I enter in just the enter key, it terminates the program with exit value: -1. Any idea what I could do? I tried looking at other similar posts but I couldn't think it through

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show more code. (Create a [mre].) Currently your question does not show any code that would exit your program. The `break` would be executed on EOF or error. If the user presses ENTER without entering any text you would get a string that contains a newline only. Maybe in this situation your parser reports an error and exits?